# SOAP: object not set to an instance of an object

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm working with the following WSDL file, which links to the popular LetMC property management software:

http://portal.letmc.com/PropertySearchService.asmx?WSDL

Using an [example class that Christian Thomas](https://github.com/industrious-mouse/letmc-php) has written, I'm trying a run a property search, which fails:

**Class**

```
<?php
/**
 * LetMC
 *
 * PHP class to allow integration with the LetMC SOAP API
 *
 * @author      Christian Thomas <christian@industriousmouse.co.uk>
 * @version     0.1
 */
class LetMC
{
    /**
     * API URL
     *
     * @access  private
     * @var string
     */
    private $api_url    = 'http://portal.letmc.com/PropertySearchService.asmx?WSDL';

    /**
     * Client ID
     *
     * @access  private
     * @var     string
     */
    private $client_id  = '{000-000-000}';

    /**
     * Property Search Defaults
     *
     * @access  private
     * @var     array
     */
    private $search_defaults = array(
        'nMaxResults'       => 10,
        'nRentMinimum'      => 0,
        'nRentMaximum'      => 0,
        'nMaximumTenants'   => -1
    );

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * GetBranches
     *
     * Return all branches by Client ID
     *
     * @access  public
     */
    public function GetBranches()
    {
        $options = array();

        $result = $this->make_request(__FUNCTION__, $options);

        if(!isset($result->GetBranchesResult)) return false;

        return $result->GetBranchesResult->BranchInfo;
    }

    /**
     * GetBranchDetails
     *
     * Return branch details by $branch_ids
     *
     * @access  public
     * @param   array   $branch_ids     Any associated Branch ID's - Strings will be typecasted
     */
    public function GetBranchDetails($branch_ids = array())
    {
        $options['objBranchIDs'] = (array) $branch_ids;

        $result = $this->make_request(__FUNCTION__, $options);

        if(!isset($result->GetBranchDetailsResult)) return false;

        return $result->GetBranchDetailsResult->BranchInfo;
    }

    /**
     * SearchProperties
     *
     * Perform a search on LetMC available properties
     *
     * @access  public
     */
    public function SearchProperties($options = array())
    {
        $options = array_merge(
            $this->search_defaults,
            $options
        );

        $result = $this->make_request(__FUNCTION__, $options);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * GetPropertyDetails
     *
     * Return all properties that match the ID's within $options['objPropertyIDs'] array
     *
     * @access  public
     */
    public function GetPropertyDetails($options = array())
    {
        $result = $this->make_request(__FUNCTION__, $options);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Make Request
     *
     * Function to perform the SOAP request
     * Returns any successful requests back to the previous function
     * Logs any failures with the $this->log() function
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string          $function   SOAP Function Name
     * @param   array           $options    Any arguments/options to pass
     * @return  mixed
     */
    private function make_request($function, $options)
    {
        // Assign the LetMC Client ID
        $options['strClientID'] = $this->client_id;

        // Instantiate SOAP Client (Force Single items to be returned as arrays for consistency)
        $client = new SoapClient(
            $this->api_url,
            array(
                'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
            )
        );

        // Perform request
        try {

            $result = $client->{$function}($options);

        } catch(SoapFault $e) {

            $this->log($e->getMessage());
            return false;

        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Log
     *
     * Logs a message to the log file (./logs)
     *
     * @access  private
     * @param   string      message to be logged
     * @return  void
     */
    private function log($message)
    {
        $dir    = dirname(__FILE__) . '/logs/';
        $file   = $dir.date('Y-m-d').'.log';

        if (!is_dir($dir)) mkdir($dir, 0755, true);

        $handle = fopen($file, 'a+');
        fwrite($handle, date('H:i:s').' -- '.$message."\n");
        fclose($handle);
    }

}
```

**Error Message**

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Cuba.Portal.PropertySearchService.SearchProperties(String strClientID, String strBranchID, Int32 nMaxResults, String strAreaID, Decimal nRentMinimum, Decimal nRentMaximum, Int32 nMaximumTenants) in z:\Cuba\Current\Portal\App_Code\PropertySearchService.cs:line 758
```

**Call**

```
<?php

$feed               = new LetMC();
$properties     = $feed->SearchProperties();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($properties);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

**Output**

```
bool(false)
```

I've previously never worked with an API, or XML/SOAP, and any help would be appreciated as to why it's failing.

### -

**RESOLVED**

Further options were required:

```
$options = array(
    'strBranchID'     => $branch_id,
    'nMaxResults'     => -1,
    'strAreaID'       => $area_id,
    'nRentMinimum'    => 0,
    'nRentMaximum'    => -1,
    'nMaximumTenants' => -1
);
```

Comment: Hi, have you ever found a solution to this? I'm on the same boat. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @Jeff you need to include additional options in the LetMC SOAP call (see above)